# Filling a junction table with mock data

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I want to fill the junction table for these two tables:

```
Create table [dbo].[Event]
(
    [id] int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    [naam] varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    [periode] date NOT NULL,
    [maxbezoeker] int NOT NULL,
    [locatie] varchar(50) NOT NULL
)

Create table [dbo].[Medewerker]
(
    [id] int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    [wachtwoord] varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    [rechten] varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    [gebruikersnaam] varchar(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL
)
```

Junction table:

```
Create table [dbo].[Event_Medewerker]
(
    [event_id] int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[Event](id) NOT NULL,
    [medewerker_id] int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[Medewerker](id) NOT NULL
)
```

The Event table and Medewerker table currently have 1000 mock entries in them. I want to link the data between them but I can't think of how I would do this other than by generating 1000 random numbers. But if I do this I feel like I would end up with a whole bunch of unlinked entries. Is there a better way of filling a junction table with mock data?

A "Medewerker" is an employee and the "Event" in this case would be a music festival. I want every Event to be linked to Medewerkers.

I'm using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio and mockaroo.com to generate data.

Comment: How do you want the data to be linked? Every event should have a medeworker? Or lots of different combinations?

Comment: Lots of different combinations. Sorry I'll add some more explanation to the post

Comment: if you have sequential ids, would there be an issue simply joining them on the id values of each table to insert the records to the link table?

Comment: Since this is only mock data I don't think that would be a problem. I do have sequential id's for both tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you could simply join your 2 tables based on the sequential ID values you have in each table, as this is mock data. Then you can use the results of the join to insert into the link table. Here's a simplified example that you can run in isolation to test:

```
CREATE TABLE #event ( id INT );

CREATE TABLE #medwerker ( id INT );

CREATE TABLE #event_medwerker
    (
      event_id INT ,
      medwerker_id INT
    );

INSERT  INTO #event
        ( id )
VALUES  ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 3 );

SELECT * FROM #event;

INSERT  INTO #medwerker
        ( id )
VALUES  ( 1 ), ( 2 ), ( 3 );

SELECT * FROM #medwerker;

INSERT  INTO #event_medwerker
        ( event_id ,
          medwerker_id
        )
        SELECT  e.id ,
                m.id
        FROM    #event e
                INNER JOIN #medwerker m ON m.id = e.id;

SELECT * FROM #event_medwerker;

DROP TABLE #event_medwerker;
DROP TABLE #event;
DROP TABLE #medwerker;
```

Answer (score 0):

**A "Medewerker" is an employee and the "Event" in this case would be a music festival. I want every Event to be linked to Medewerkers.**

In that case, you could use this query

```
DECLARE @Event AS TABLE(id int)

DECLARE @Medewerker AS TABLE(id int)

DECLARE @Event_Medewerker AS TABLE (EventId int, MedewerkerId int)

INSERT INTO @Event
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9),(10)

INSERT INTO @Medewerker
VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9),(10)

INSERT INTO  @Event_Medewerker (EventId, MedewerkerId)
SELECT e.id AS EventID, md.id AS MedewerkerId
FROM 

(SELECT * FROM @Event t) e 

CROSS APPLY

(
SELECT TOP (ABS(Checksum(NewID()) % 10) + 2) * FROM @Medewerker t ORDER BY newid()  -- random 2 - 12 item bat ki o bang @Medewerker
) md

ORDER BY e.id, md.id

SELECT * FROM @Event_Medewerker em
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a temp table to fill with all possible combinations, including a random ordering number. Then iterate all events, each time determine a random amount and insert from the temp table using the random ordering number to determine the random amount.

Something like this:

```
BEGIN
    -- temp table
    DECLARE @dummy_table table(Event_id int, Medewerker_id int, Order_nr int)

    -- insert all possible combinations with a random order nr
    insert into @dummy_table(Event_id, Medewerker_id, Order_nr)
    select
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY e.id ORDER BY newid() ASC),  -- use newid() to randomize order
        e.id,
        m.id
    from
        Event e
        join Medewerker m -- cross join

    -- cursor for all events
    DECLARE cur_evts CURSOR FOR SELECT Id FROM Event; 
    DECLARE @Event_id int
    DECLARE @random_amount int

    OPEN cur_evts;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_evts INTO @Event_id;

    -- iterate all events
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
    BEGIN
        -- random amount between 50..500
        SET @random_amount = 50 + (450 * RAND(convert(varbinary, newid())))

        insert into Event_Medewerker(event_id, medewerker_id)
        select
            event_id,
            medewerker_id
        from
            @dummy_table
        where
            Event_id = @Event_id
            and order_nr < @random_amount

        FETCH NEXT FROM cur_evts INTO @Event_id;
    END
    CLOSE cur_evts;
    DEALLOCATE cur_evts;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Sample schema with data

---

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Event') IS NOT NULL
Drop table [Event]
Create table [dbo].[Event]
(
    [id] int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    [naam] varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    [periode] date NOT NULL,
    [maxbezoeker] int NOT NULL,
    [locatie] varchar(50) NOT NULL
)

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Medewerker') IS NOT NULL
Drop table [Medewerker]
Create table [dbo].[Medewerker]
(
    [id] int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
    [wachtwoord] varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    [rechten] varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    [gebruikersnaam] varchar(30) UNIQUE NOT NULL
)


 IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.Event_Medewerker') IS NOT NULL
  Drop table [Event_Medewerker]
Create table [dbo].[Event_Medewerker]
(
    [event_id] int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[Event](id) NOT NULL,
    [medewerker_id] int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES [dbo].[Medewerker](id) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO [Event]
(
 naam
,periode
,maxbezoeker
,locatie
)
SELECT 'Harry','2017-04-04',77,'dsghvgj'Union All
SELECT 'Harry','2017-04-04',77,'dsghvgj'Union All
SELECT 'Harry','2017-04-04',77,'dsghvgj'Union All
SELECT 'Harry','2017-04-04',77,'dsghvgj'

INSERT INTO [Medewerker]
(
wachtwoord
,rechten
,gebruikersnaam
)

SELECT 'Gills','three month','ggg' Union All
SELECT 'Gills','three month','ANbc' Union All
SELECT 'Gills','three month','ANbaac' Union All
SELECT 'Gills','three month','ooooANbc' 


SELECT * FROM [Event]
SELECT * FROM [Medewerker]
SELECT * FROM [Event_Medewerker]
```

---

Inserting data into bridge table code

---

```
DECLARE @Event INT
    ,@Medewerker INT
    ,@RecordCount INT
    ,@minid INT = 1
    ,@maxid INT

SELECT @RecordCount = COUNT(1) FROM [Event] inner join [Medewerker] on [Event].id=[Medewerker].id

SET @maxid = @RecordCount

    WHILE (@minid <= @maxid)
    BEGIN
        SELECT @Event =  id FROM [Event]
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM [Event_Medewerker] Em
                WHERE em.event_id = [Event].id
                )
            AND id = @minid

        SELECT @Medewerker =  id FROM [Medewerker]
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1
                FROM [Event_Medewerker] Em
                WHERE em.event_id = [Medewerker].id
                )
            AND id = @minid

        INSERT INTO [Event_Medewerker]
         (
            event_id
            ,medewerker_id
            )
        SELECT @Event,@Medewerker

        SET @minid = @minid + 1
    END
```